# How do you load an ASCII file into netlogo?

Tags: gis, netlogo

Why does changing a file name prevent me from loading the file?

I am trying to load an ASCII file into Netlogo. I downloaded the GIS General Examples Model from Netlogo and it ran fine. Then I just tried changing the name of the ASCII file from world-elevation to world-elevation2 and I saved and closed the file. I changed the name in Netlogo from loading "data/world-elevation.asc" to loading "data/world-elevation2.asc" but now it won't work and says "Extension exception: invalid column count marker on line 1 error while observer running GIS:LOAD-DATASET." Why won't it work when all I did was change the name of the file?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: (i) you either changed more about the file than its name, or (ii) you did not change it to the name you think you did.  Both of these things can easily happen by accident.

You indicate that you had the data open in some application.  Was that application simply a good ASCII text editor?  If not, anything might have happened: changes to the fileformat (UNIX vs Windows), the fileencoding, or even the file extension.  But if so, some text editors will by default append a ".txt" extension when saving a file.  See if that happened.  (If you are on Windows, some version hide extensions by default, so you will have to change that to make sure you are seeing the actual extension of your file.)

Recommendation: use a command shell (e.g., `Terminal` on Mac or `powershell` on Windows) to safely copy files.